# Why binded value doesn`t show in the TextBlock?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding

I try bind string to TextBlock Text property, but value isn`t show on my view.

xaml:

```
<TextBlock Margin="10,0" DataContext="{Binding UpgradeViewModel, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">
                <Run Text="Other features: " FontWeight="Bold"/>
                <Run Text="{Binding UpgradeViewModel.AdditionalSelectedLevelData, Source={StaticResource Locator}, 
                            Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            </TextBlock>
```

view model:

```
private string additionalSelectedLevelData;
public string AdditionalSelectedLevelData
        {
            get => additionalSelectedLevelData;
            set
            {
                Set(ref additionalSelectedLevelData, value);
                Debug.WriteLine(value);
            }
        }
```

Property changed values, I check it using Debug.WriteLine(value);

I have realization for INotifyPropertyChanged (Set(ref additionalSelectedLevelData, value);), set binding mode to TwoWay, set UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged.

I try add TextBox and bind to his Text property same string value, and have the same result, but when I typing in textbox string showed on TextBlock and TextBox. I have any ideas. Binding path correct 100%.

[image: correct value]

Comment: You already set DataContext at the level of `TextBlock` and need not repeat the same at `Run`. So, only the property name will be enough.

Comment: Please show how you first initialize `additionalSelectedLevelData`.

Comment: @JesseGood I add initialization for this field, value showed, but not changed.

Comment: @emoacht I try this, get some result

Comment: Please remember to show more context next time, please. Posting code snippets alone never can help a stranger to your code to "debug" it by review. Always post a minimal viable code example that reproduces the error. Creating this example can also help to identify the problem yourself.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am creating ViewModel twice, I fixed it and problem
disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

I have removed the `UpgradeViewModel` from Run Text as `TextBlock` already binded to it. Also removed the static resource from Run Text for same reason.
As long as the `INotifyPropertyChanged` is implemented properly and `ViewModel` Locator works then it should be working fine

```
<TextBlock Margin="10,0" DataContext="{Binding UpgradeViewModel, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">
    <Run Text="Other features: " FontWeight="Bold"/>
    <Run Text="{Binding AdditionalSelectedLevelData, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: Its not working for me :(

Comment: Your "fix" is correct in a way that it simplifies the really confused Binding. The original Binding targets the Source value and not the DataContext, therefore it works.

Comment: Please go through below data binding video for beginners
https://youtu.be/w-GIskKhATw